# How to internally rewrite a page when requested from specific HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, drupal, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Drupal site, `example.com`, and our client has a campaign that they're promoting for which they've bought a new domain name, `campaign.com`. I'd like it so that a request for `campaign.com` internally rewrites to a particular page of the Drupal site. Note Drupal uses an .htaccess file in the document root.

The normal Drupal rewrite is

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I added the following *before* the normal rewrite.

```
# Custom URLS (eg. microsites) go here
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =campaign.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule ^ index.php?q=node/22 [L]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, it just shows the homepage. Turning on the rewrite log I get this.

```
1. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/ -> 
2. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] applying pattern '^' to uri ''
3. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (2) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] rewrite '' -> 'index.php?q=node/22'
4. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?q=node/22 -> uri=index.php, args=q=node/22
5. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> D:/wamp/www/index.php
6. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (2) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip document_root prefix: D:/wamp/www/index.php -> /index.php
7. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (1) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
8. [rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/index.php -> index.php
9. [rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
10.[rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/index.php -> index.php
11.[rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
12.[rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] pass through D:/wamp/www/index.php
```

I'm not used to mod_rewrite, so I might be missing something, but comparing the logs from a call to `http://example.com/node/3` and from `http://campaign.com/` I can't see any meaningful difference. Specifically the URI and *args* on line 4 seem correct, the internal redirect on line 7 seems right, and the pass through on line 12 seems right (because the file `index.php` exists). But for some reason it seems the query string's been discarded/ignored around the time of the internal redirect. I'm completely stumped.

Also, if anyone could provide a reference on understanding the rewrite log, that might help. It'd be great if there's a way to track the query string through the internal redirect.

FWIW I'm using WampServer 2.1 with Apache 2.2.17.

Comment: i think your RewriteLog level is too low and leaving out RewriteCond comparisons.  When you make any substitution in per-directory/htaccess context, the entire ruleset will run again, so the default rule you mention might stomp on your rule you've inserted the 2nd time around.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was already at the maximum level, but checking the docs that's 9 and I'm way below that. Will see if the more detailed log helps me, and if not I'll post it here. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're registering a new domain, couldn't you set up page where at that location and do a redirect to any page/link in your current site?

Comment: @digit1001 - I was looking for an internal rewrite, rather than an external redirect. (But I ran out of time and handled it as a redirect in the end!)

Comment: I facing the same situation and still not quite sure what i need to do? Andy, have u figured it all out? thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `httpd.conf` for `campaign.com` with it pulling data from `example.com/macguffin/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName campaign.com

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyPass / http://example.com/macguffin/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/macguffin/

<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks, I've not played with the Proxy related directives before. Do you know if it's impossible to do what I was trying just with mod_rewrite?

Comment: At the end of the day you want it to be http://www.campaign.com/ instead of http://mac.guffin.com/mac/guffin/123 that appears in the URL address bar of people's browsers. The only way to do that is with Proxy and its related cousins ProxyPassReverse (unless you are hiding the URL with iframe). This will double your bandwidth at campaign.com but this will not be a problem if that is on loopback of your host.